# Google PHP API - Does each user have to go through the API console to allow your app to work?

Tags: php, api, oauth, calendar

This is a tough question to ask so I hope I can make it clear!

I'm writing a PHP script that access a users Gmail calendar.  I first wrote it using Zend and it was fantastic, but found that I have to use the Oauth to get to tasks - therefore I rewrote it for Oauth instead.

In order to use Oauth I have to go to my API console and set up the account and then I have access and everything works great.  Here is my problem: I can't ask every single user to go through this somewhat technical step of creating a key and all of that just so my app can work with their Gmail.

Zend was really easy, the user provides me with their name and password and I have access.  Now I don't see any way to change accounts using the Oauth method, all of the credentials are for a SINGLE Gmail account (as far as I can tell).

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do without making the users go through fifteen hoops to allow me access?  I would like to register my app and get my keys, then be able to point to ANY Gmail account, the user grant me access, and I'm in.  Otherwise each user has to go to the API console in their own Gmail, create branding, create a key and then create a server ID, THEN provide that all to me so I can plug it in and THEN redirect them back to Google so they can say "yes, I accept this".  That's a lot of steps to integrate.

I hope this was clear enough :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's basically how OAuth works. ONLY the developer that wrote the app needs to register it, get the keys and add that to the configuration.

Users of the app simply get taken to a page (after signing into their Google account) where they will grant access to your app in a single click. Google will remember their decision and the next time will be even faster.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that because I was already logged into my Gmail account that it kept using that one.